# iOS: UIView origin y not changing on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikeyboard

I'm trying to set my `self.mainView.frame.origin.y` when the `keyboard` is displaying. It works fine on `iOS 11` but not in `iOS 9`.

This is my code:

```
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 1 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
        self.mainView.frame.origin.y -= 150
        self.mainView.setNeedsLayout()
        self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded()
        print("=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 2 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
        return true
    }



    internal func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("=== textFieldShouldReturn 1 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
        self.mainView.frame.origin.y = self.normalMainViewOriginY
        textField.endEditing(true)
        print("=== textFieldShouldReturn 2 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
        return true
    }
```

In the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.normalMainViewOriginY = self.mainView.frame.origin.y
```

I tested also the same think using `NSNotification` but I'm getting the same problem in `iOS 9`

Those are the prints output:

**iOS 9:**

=== normalMainViewOriginY: 243.0 (from `viewDidLoad()`)

=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 1: 208.5

=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 2: 208.5

=== textFieldShouldReturn 1: 208.5

=== textFieldShouldReturn 2: 243.0

**iOS 11:**

=== normalMainViewOriginY: 243.0 (from `viewDidLoad()`)

=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 1: 208.5

=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 2: 58.5

=== textFieldShouldReturn 1: 58.5

=== textFieldShouldReturn 2: 243.0

Comment: Is  self.mainView == self.view ?????

Comment: @Sh_Khan no the mainView is inside the view. It's a modal containing a rectangular mainView with textField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that changing frames doesn't affect the underlining layout constraints , so try constraints it won't fail , say you have the top constraint of mainView as `mainViewTopCon`

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 1 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
    self.mainViewTopCon.constant -= 150
    self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded()
    print("=== textFieldShouldBeginEditing 2 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
    return true
}

internal func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    print("=== textFieldShouldReturn 1 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
    self.mainViewTopCon.constant = 0 // or value in IB that you set initally 
    self.mainView.layoutIfNeeded()
    textField.endEditing(true)
    print("=== textFieldShouldReturn 2 \(self.mainView.frame.origin.y) ")
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer? But way it's working in iOS 11?

Comment: @Sh_Khan You are assuming that constraints are being used. There's no mention if that is the case or not.

Comment: @NeAS  I think they may take in account frame changes to be reflected in constraints for new ios versions , but that won't work in old versions , but auto-layout change will surely reflected

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks again. My mainView is centered vertically, so I will set the constant of this constraint and tell you if it's working.

Comment: @rmaddy I assumed that because i don't think there are any developers still use frame-layout in IB (or if there may not exceed 5%)

Comment: @NeAS  yes hook centerY constraint instead